# Proper pidfile usage

Tags: windows, linux, unix, process

I am unclear on the need and the usage of a pid-file and I wanted to know what is the correct usage of a pidfile and what are the best practices surrounding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in linux, typically in /var/run there are pidfiles listed for all currently running processes and they contain, obviously, the process id. so when you use commands like **ps aux**, and they list the process id (PID) as a column, you may use them as a base of comparison

Comment: It is not all currently running processes - it is usually only daemon processes, of which it only makes sense for one to be running.  Additionally, for daemons that fork long-running child processes (like Apache), the pidfile might only contain the pid of the "head" process.